# Myst: Masterpiece Edition VS realMyst

Tags: version-differences, myst-series

Hi guys since this weekend I can get those games with a discount (only 3 bucks each!) I'm going to buy one of them.

Now, I'm new to the Myst saga.  What significant differences are there between realMyst and Myst Masterpiece Edition?

Comment: This is late but it is worth mentioning, if money is an object, Buy Riven. It is 10 times the game that Myst is, and you do not need to play Myst first. Play it after you get hooked on Riven.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The main difference between the two games is that Myst and Myst: Masterpiece Edition are 2D games, while realMyst and [realMyst Masterpiece Edition](http://cyan.com/games/realmyst-masterpiece-edition/) are 3D games.  All version tell the same story, except that the realMyst games have the Rime age not found in the 2D games.

In the 2D versions of Myst, you can only go to certain locations and turn to fixed viewpoints.  In the 3D version of Myst, you can explore anywhere.

The main difference between Myst and Myst: Masterpiece Edition is that the former uses an 8-bit color palette, while the latter uses a 24-bit color palette.  This is a noticeable difference if you play the two games.

The main difference between realMyst and realMyst: Masterpiece Edition is that the latter uses redone textures of a much higher quality as well as running in a higher screen resolution.

On a side note: Myst's first sequel, Riven, is a 2D-only game.  It's also considerably larger and more difficult than the original Myst.

Note: There are 4 more Myst games after Riven.  They are:

- Myst III: Exile - A person who has a grudge against Atrus steals his latest linking book to what is Atrus's new home.  You need to get it back.
- Myst IV: Revelation - Atrus's daughter is missing, you need to find her.  Also reintroduces Atrus's sons from the first game.
- Myst V: End of Ages - The final game in the main storyline.
- URU: Ages Beyond Myst - Not in the normal Myst storyline and uses a different game engine.  It was developed as an online game, but also has offline components.  The online component was discontinued for a while, but appears to be [back](http://mystonline.com/) now.

Comment: RealMyst could be played in "point and click" mode (the panorama) or in full WASD motion. (Which is the far better method IMO).

Comment: realMyst is full 3D, like any FPS.

Comment: On a side note, in the 3 years since I originally answered this question (I'm user2974), Cyan released a [realMyst Masterpiece Edition](http://cyan.com/games/realmyst-masterpiece-edition/).

Comment: @Powerlord One minor complaint with this answer: Myst V isn't really part of the 'main storyline', it's actually more of a follow on to the storyline of Uru and only features a few references to the 'main storyline'.

Comment: I probably should update this answer again since they've released another version of the original Myst.

Answer (score 15):

When they originally did Myst, the 24-bit rendered views (~2,500 of them) were downsampled to 8 bit to load quickly from early CD-Roms.

The Masterpiece edition uses full-quality images (and remastered sound) but the models and textures themselves haven't been updated - so to me it feels a little like you can see the rendering imperfections better. (See below how pixelated the path / column textures are [more clearly visible at full-screen sizes]). There are also colour improvements - try opening them in 2 tabs and switching back and forth.

Conversely, RealMyst is a complete re-texture and (I believe) re-model of the world with a free-moving perspective. IMHO It looks prettier and plays better.

#### Original

[image: Myst Comparison Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [cyan.com](http://cho.cyan.com/RAWA/MystCompare/Myst8.jpg))</sub>

#### Masterpiece Edition

[image: Myst: Masterpiece Edition Comparison Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [cyan.com](http://cho.cyan.com/RAWA/MystCompare/Myst24.jpg))</sub>

#### RealMyst

[image: RealMyst Comparison Screenshot]

Someone has also put together a video comparing these versions and some of the more recent additions:

Answer (score 6):

Definitely recommend RealMyst over Masterpiece Edition - not for the Ryme age (although that's not a small bonus), but because the improvement in graphics and control. (And you can choose to play RealMyst in "point and click" mode like the original, but I'd recommend the first-person WASD controls - there's a lot of detail you miss by sticking to the main path.)

Riven is simultaneously my most and least favorite game in the Myst canon. Most favorite because it's the largest single world and everything is internally consistant (all the puzzles have an in-story reason for existing). Least favorite because it is soul-crushingly hard. They don't make games like that anymore.

So, in short: get RealMyst and Riven, and a good hint guide for the latter. :)

Comment: Hint guides ruin it! :)

Comment: @ERJ I would normally agree (and I'd say get as far as you can before cracking open the hint guide!), but Riven in particular has a couple puzzles that... well, mere mortals aren't likely to get the solution any time soon. :)

Answer (score 5):

Myst: ME is node based, with individual screens.
realMyst is full 3D.

the story is the same and the graphics are pretty close. Personally I prefer the classic style of Myst: ME, and think that the graphics are slightly more stylish.

realMyst does have a few minor additions. The only important ones being Ti'ana's grave stone, and a small but interesting bonus age after the game is finished.

If money is an object buy Riven, you do not have to play Myst first and Riven is 10 times the game Myst is.

Answer (score 2):

I personally think realMyst is much more involving than either the original or the masterpiece version. More so when you consider the Rime age is only available in realMyst.

And yes Riven is worth it for more in-depth puzzles, story and environment (if you can get past the now aging graphics that haven't been updated in newer re-releases).

Comment: I didn't feel that the Rime age added much to the game.

Comment: Whether it added to the game or not it is still an extra element only found in realMyst (and later ports to other consoles). And most hardcore Myst fans, myself included, appreciate any new ages they can get their hands on.

Answer (score 1):

In the Realmyst Masterpiece Edition, in the Selenitic Age, there is a submarine section with a 'track maze' part in it.

This maze is underwater in the original Myst and it is above water in the Realmyst version.

Comment: Welcome to arqade.se ^^ Take the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already and read the [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) if in need of guidance.